# Running Specflow tests in TFS Build

Tags: tfs, bdd, specflow, alm

How can I get my TFS build to run my Specflow tests? I have the tests running in the local VS build, but they aren't being picked up in the TFS build. Please could someone post the steps I would take to have the build run the specflow tests, and report on the results. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I guess specflow uses nunit tests. you need to set up nunit in build server

http://www.mytechfinds.com/articles/software-testing/6-test-automation/72-running-nunit-tests-from-team-foundation-server-2012-continuous-integration-build

Comment: Thanks, but I've already got my NUnit tests working. It is information about how to get Specflow running in TFS that is hard to find.

Comment: Specflow doesn't have its own runner. It really does just use nUnit unless you've set it up to use mstest. All you should have to do is point your runner at the specflow tests in the same way that you point it at your nunit tests.

Comment: Thanks, both of you, I made some progress, and got this working in TeamCity using a MSBuild project to run the tests. I need to port this experience across to TFS. At one point the error I got was to do with not being able to find the NUnit runner. I think if I install NUnit on the build server I can get it working, it is pretty easy to have the build run another MSBuild project, which should sort my issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [SpecRun](http://www.specrun.com), it will automatically take care of TFS Build integration. Installing SpecRun is just referring the NuGet package from the SpecFlow project.